# Load an assembly from plugin

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, autodesk-navisworks

### INTRODUCTION

I'm writing a plugin for Navisworks and i'm using the Dropbox api to download/upload documents from a repository.

### PROBLEM

*Dropbox.Api* uses the **Newtonsoft.Json.dll** version **7.0**, the problem is that *Navisworks* uses the **4.0** version of the **same** assembly, so I cannot use the Dropbox api because it throws an exception every time:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, ...

So as I understand the program has the assembly 4.0v so Dropbox.Api cannot execute properly.

By now, what I've done is to use another process which I can load the right assembly and download/upload the files from there, but I would like to avoid using a second process.

I'm trying to use reflection to load the assembly at runtime, but it takes no effect, the program still cannot find the newer assembly.

```
//Load the assembly at the beginning of the plugin
var ass = System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(Properties.Resources.Newtonsoft_Json);

//Use the Dropbox api
//Exception...
```

Can I force, somehow, the program to use the newer assembly (temporary)?

Is there some solution that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering this issue because you cannot load two different **non**-*strong-named* versions of a .NET assembly (no matter where it is on the file system) into the same AppDomain.  By default you start with a single AppDomain called the Primary AppDomain for your process.

A strong-named assembly is one that takes the filename; version; signing key and culture to produce a unique assembly.

> By now, what I've done is to use another process which I can load the right assembly and download/upload the files from there, but I would like to avoid using a second process.

No need to create a second process, you can instead create a **2nd AppDomain** in the **same process**.  Each AppDomain can load different versions of assemblies including Newtonsoft.Json without conflict.

> I'm trying to use reflection to load the assembly at runtime, but it takes no effect, the program still cannot find the newer assembly.

That won't work, it's essentially the same as letting .NET doing it for you automatically.

The only time when you can load multiple versions of .NET assemblies into the same AppDomain is if the assembly (in this case the NuGet package) and dependent assemblies are **all strong-named**.  For some reason I have never been able to fathom is why most open source .NET devs refuse to strong-name assemblies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've not been able to solve the problem using a second AppDomain, it keeps throwing an exception, I guess that the problem is more complex, I've also tried to load the assembly in the current AppDomain, It loads the assembly with the newer version but still it doesn't find it. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Dom93 what example did you follow to create AppDomains?

Comment: Resource of AppDomain: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Dom93 Thanks.  AppDomains is the way to do it.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21973354/585968) goes into it a bit more.  A full example is pretty long and the process complicated sadly.  The most important thing to remember is to create a `[MarshalByRef] class MyProxy` that does all of the loading for you **in the child AppDomain**. There was a wonderful MSDN Magaznine article called _"[Do you trust it? Extensibility]"_ (??) circa ~2005 which went into it in great detail

Comment: @Dom93 generally you don't provide code for someone's answer (when no code existed before, SO isn't really a Wiki).  Also, the code you provided had the problem whereby you were loading the same assembly in question **twice**, once in the child domain, but more importantly, you were also loading it in the parent domain, something you wouldn't want to do in your particular case as it locks down your primary AppDomain to that version.   I appreciate your effort though.  Don't forget, you can always answer your own questions by posting an answer yourself. :)

Comment: thanks for the advice and the answer, I will keep working on the code.

Comment: @Dom93 another wonderful feature of child AppDomains is that if you ever needed to _unload_ an assembly, you just nuke the child AppDomain by calling `Unload()`.  However you cannot unload assemblies loaded in the Primary AppDomain sadly. :)